# How to add VerifyCsrfToken exception for api in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, echo, csrf

I want to implement socket with Echo in laravel. I have an API beside my main laravel project. In my laravel project all events are triggered and sockets working correctly. But in API it doesn't work and it returns 419 error. `Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 419`. I figured out that it needs CSRF token however in API we don't have it. By the way when I comment `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` in `App\Http\Kernel.php` it works!

How can I add it to an exception that if an user sending request to API not to verify its CSRF token?

Answer (score 0):

Btw, you can put URIs that you want to make as exception inside this file `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` at following line:

```
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    //

];
```

Those URIs under `$except` property will be ignore

Comment: What should I put here?! if I put the uri of what is in website side, it ignores verifying for website too. However I want it only for API.

Comment: Your url definition that you defined in API route file. How many routes you want to add an exception?

Comment: All of them. Because in API we don't have laravel csrf token.

Comment: By default, API route dont have `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware tied to its

Comment: And my surprise is exactly at that point. I don't know why it needs VerifyCsrfToken.

Comment: Are you sure its called the API route instead of Web route?

Comment: Thank you @NorlihazmeyGhazali :) that was my fault.

Comment: What happened actually?

Comment: I had set my route which was `echo-auth` in `web.php` however it should have been in `api.php`. I didn't move from `web.php` to `api.php` but I just added the exception in that file you mentioned. Thanks :)